# How to resolve hostnames from a intranet interface?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a public IP and some hostnames pointing to it, on this public IP server I have others intranet interfaces running **apache virtual hosts servers**, my question is how can I forward external requests to this interfaces?

On a simple apache virtual hosts running in the public IP machine I can easy do that editing `/etc/hosts` this way

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
127.0.0.1 blog.mysite.com
```

But by some motive it not work with intranet interfaces

```
172.17.0.1 mysite.com
172.17.0.2 blog.mysite.com
172.17.0.2 news.mysite.com
```

ps: A apache server is running on each IP

I simple get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, if a ping it I get the server IP, so the public DNS are working

Can you help me?

Comment: The problem it self is that

Answer (score 0):

## The solution

Ok hours later I found the answer, is very simple:

You need to have another **apache** instance or whatever like it running on port `80` for this case and create virtual hosts to resolve the hostnames to the intranet ips.

## More explanation

If I have **apache** running in others intranet IPs they are not visible on public IP, if someone access `myhost.com` he will be pointed to `0.0.0.0:80` (public ip), so in this port you need to have some service that understand the request and forward it to the respective internal host, apache do that.